# Remove part of url with URL Rewrite Apache

Tags: php, regex, apache

I am using Apache rewrite rules

I have the following rule which is working well

```
RewriteRule .(needredirect) /info.php
```

My rule correctly matches neededredirect in the url below

```
http://example.com/en/needredirect=1
```

I now go to the info page as required

How do I enhance this rule so that the new location no longer has needredirect?

Cheers

Paul